# APPCRASH (not when debugging) and Segmentation fault using QtCreator (C/C++)

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, qt-creator, crash

I'm using QtCreator to code an algorithm that I have already coded on Matlab.

When coding this program, I have two errors. The firts one (APPCRASH) appears just when I build and execute the program normally, but not when I try to debug it (Heisenbug) and it appears on the function 'matriceA'. I tried to make the variables volatile and to write the matrix A term formulas on other function, hoping that that will stop the compiler optimization (I think that the compiler optimization might cause the problem), but I have not been able to solve the problem. I have not tried to to compile the project using the option -o0 because my professor (it's an university project) has to be able to compile it normally (without specific options).

The second one is a SISSEGV segmentation fault. It happens when the code arrives to "DestroyFloatArray(&b, width);" on InpaintingColor.

And here the codes:

clanu_process.cpp (it's little messy because I've tried a lot of things...)

```
#include "clanu_process.h"
#include "iomanip"


void InpaintingColor(float **Rout, float **Gout, float **Bout, float **Rin, float **Gin, float **Bin, float **Mask, int width, int height, double param)
{
    cout << "1" << endl;
    float alphak = 0, bethak = 0, res = 0;
    float **b = 0, **xk = 0, **dk = 0, **rk = 0, **Ark = 0, **tmp1 = 0,**tmp2 = 0,**tmp3 = 0;
    Ark = AllocateFloatArray( width, height);
    tmp1 = AllocateFloatArray( width, height);
    tmp2 = AllocateFloatArray( width, height);
    tmp3 = AllocateFloatArray( width, height);
    xk = AllocateFloatArray( width, height);
    dk = AllocateFloatArray( width, height);
    rk = AllocateFloatArray( width, height);
    b = AllocateFloatArray( width, height);

    cout << "2" << endl;
    res = 1e8;
    matrixProductByScalar(b,1.0/(3.0*256),Rin,width,height);
    matrixDuplicate(xk, b, width, height);
    // APPCRASH error
    matriceA(Ark,xk,Mask,width,height);

    //More code

    // SIGSEGV error
    DestroyFloatArray(&b, width);
    DestroyFloatArray(&xk, width);
    DestroyFloatArray(&dk, width);
    DestroyFloatArray(&rk, width);
    DestroyFloatArray(&Ark, width);
    DestroyFloatArray(&tmp1, width);
    DestroyFloatArray(&tmp2, width);
    DestroyFloatArray(&tmp3, width);
}
float** matriceA(float **A, float **I, float **Masque, int N2, int N1){
    volatile bool bool_iplus = false, bool_imoins = false, bool_jmoins = false, bool_jplus = false;
    volatile int iplus = 0, imoins = 0, jplus = 0, jmoins = 0;

    for(int i = 1; i <= N1; i++){
        bool_iplus = i<N1;
        iplus = i+1 < N1 ? i+1 : N1;
        bool_imoins = i>1;
        imoins = i-1 > 1 ? i-1 : 1;

        for(int j = 1; j <= N2; j++){

            bool_jplus = j<N2;
            jplus = j+1 < N2 ? j+1 : N2;
            bool_jmoins = j>1;
            jmoins = j -1 > 1 ? j-1 : 1;
            if(Masque[i-1][j-1]!=0){
                //cout << "if - " << i << ", " << j<< endl;
                A[i-1][j-1] = (1.0/36)*(16*I[i-1][j-1]
                 + 4*(
                    (bool_iplus?I[iplus-1][j-1]:0)
                    + (bool_imoins?I[imoins-1][j-1]:0)
                    + (bool_jplus?I[i-1][jplus-1]:0)
                    + (bool_jmoins?I[i-1][jmoins-1]:0)
                 )+(
                    (bool_iplus&&bool_jplus?I[iplus-1][jplus-1]:0)
                    + (bool_imoins&&bool_jplus?I[imoins-1][jplus-1]:0)
                    + (bool_imoins&&bool_jmoins?I[imoins-1][jmoins-1]:0))
                 + (bool_iplus&&bool_jmoins?I[iplus-1][jmoins-1]:0));
            }else{
                //cout << "else - " << i << ", " << j << endl;
                A[i-1][j-1]=
                    -(1.0*N1*N2)*(
                        -8.0*I[i-1][j-1]
                        + I[iplus-1][j-1]
                        + I[imoins-1][j-1]
                        + I[i-1][jplus-1]
                        + I[i-1][jmoins-1]
                        + I[iplus-1][jplus-1]
                        + I[imoins-1][jplus-1]
                        + I[imoins-1][jmoins-1]
                        + I[iplus-1][jmoins-1]);
            }
        }
    }
    return A;
}
```

The functions AllocateFloatArray and DestroyFloatArray

```
float ** AllocateFloatArray(int width, int height)
{
    float ** r = new float*[width];
    for(int i=0; i<width; i++)
        r[i] = new float[height];
    return r;
}

void DestroyFloatArray(float ***a, int width)
{
    if( *a == 0 ) return;
    for(int i=0; i<width; i++)
        delete[] a[0][i];
    delete[] *a;
    *a = 0;
}
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I hardly believe this is a minimal example of your problem ;)

Comment: [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thank you.

Comment: You should narrow down the problem and remove everything that has nothing to do with it. At this moment it is harder to read your question than to solve the problem.

Comment: Sorry. It's the first time I write a post, so I tried to be as concise as possible. I'll reduce a bit in fast as I can

Comment: I've written the part of the code that has the errors at the end of the file, as well as a reduced formulation. (I left everything else in case you need it). I hope it is enough, and thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm no sure that it's the cause of your problem but...

Your function "Matrix operations" (`sum()`, `matrixSubstraction()`, `matrixAddition()`, `matrixProductByElement()`, `matrixProductByScalar()`, and `matrixDuplicate()`) are ranging the first index from zero to `width` and the second one from zero to `height`.

If I'm not wrong, this is correct and is consistent with allocation/deallocation (`AllocateFloatArray()` and `DestroyFloatArray()`).

But look at the two `matriceA()` functions; they are defined as

```
float** matriceA(float **A, float **I, int N2, int N1)
float** matriceA(float **A, float **I, float **Masque, int N2, int N1)
```

In both functions the first index range from zero to `N1` and the second one from zero to `N2`; by example

```
for(int i = 1; i <= N1; i++){
// ...
   for(int j = 1; j <= N2; j++){
   // ...
      A[i-1][j-1] = (1.0/36)*(16*I[i-1][j-1] // ...
```

Good. But you call `matriceA()` in this way

```
matriceA(Ark,rk,Mask,width,height);
```

Briefly: you allocate your matrices as `width * height` matrices; your "matrix operations" are using they as `width * height` matrices but your `matriceA()` function are using they as `height * width`.

Wonderful way to devastate the memory.

I suppose the solution could be

1) switch `N1` and `N2` in `matriceA()` definition

2) or switch `width` and `height` in `matriceA()` calling

p.s.: sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Thank you! You were right. You didn't solve the problems I was talking about but you found another one.

Comment: And do not worry about your english. I'm not native, and my english it's not the best  either

Comment: I was mistaken. The error you found solved all the problems. Yesterday, when changed the code, I did not do It right. Thank you again